# Linking to local subdomains

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, navbar, href

I made a nav bar for my website that has three pages, all in the same directory.

1. `index.php` has 2 sections: `#donate` and `#info`.
2. `quiz.html` is just one page.
3. `contact.html` is just one page.

   On `index.php` my navbar works perfectly. Here is the code:

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large"><strong>HOME</strong></a>
    <a href="/quiz.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">QUESTIONAIRRE</a>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
      <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="More">MORE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
        <a href="#info" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">INFO</a>
        <a href="/contact.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="#donate" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">DONATE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But when I use the navbar on `quiz.html`, When I hit "DONATE" or "CONTACT", it doesn't work- it takes me to `quiz.html#`, even though "INFO" has the same syntax, and works. Here is the code for `quiz.html`'s navbar:

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            <a href="/index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">HOME</a>
            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large"><strong>QUESTIONAIRRE</strong></a>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
                <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="More">MORE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
                    <a href="/index.php/#info" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">INFO</a>
                    <a href="/contact.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACT</a>
                    <a href="/index.php/#donate" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">DONATE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The same problem occurs in `contact.html`, where it can't go to "CONTACT" or "DONATE"
I tried absolute linking, but it didn't help.

(You can look at the problem [here](http://hosty.epizy.com), but I don't have a ssl cert yet)

How can I fix the references?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by making all of the pages (`index`,`contact` and `quiz`) into `.php` instead of some being `.html`. I guess there is some problem cross-referencing between them.